# AR shows blank instead of video

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, vuforia

so I when I test the AR in Unity everything works properly but when I export it to apk and test it on my phone the video doesn't play, it just shows as blank quad. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiZ5S.jpg)

I tried following this tutorial but since it's from 5 yrs ago not everything is exactly the same
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtiUx_szKbI&t=837s
Tried re doing whole AR set up, restarting my computer and making sure i followed the tutorial correctly.

I would really appreciative your help since i need this app to pass my class at uni. And please explain how to fix it as you were explaining it to a 7 yo.
Thank you, a tried art student

Comment: I would suggest following the official getting started guide available on the vuforia engine portal here https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-unity

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the **MainCamera** tag for the AR Camera?

Comment: the tag has been set as maincamera automagically, i haven't changed anything aside was I was taught at class or was mentioned in tutorial i linked above